Do I need a `HOLDLOCK` on a `MERGE` that's not sourcing from another table?
I need to know whether the following pattern requires me to use HOLDLOCK in a very highly concurrent environment. Particularly note that the source is not another table. It's basically parameters that have been passed to the query.
MERGE INTO table1 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING (
    SELECT 
        @ID AS ID,
        ...
) AS source
ON (target.ID = source.ID AND ...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, ...)
    VALUES (source.ID, ...)

I've only put it in out of precaution, since I've been reading about the pitfalls of MERGE. In my own dev-testing though (still very highly concurrent), it doesn't seem to make a difference. I never run into a concurrency problem even without the HOLDLOCK.
I can't use INSERT INTO table1 ... WHERE ... DOES NOT EXISTS (... SELECT table1 ...) pattern, because that runs into concurrency problems, even with HOLDLOCK in place. So the MERGE was my solution to it, I am just not sure if I need the HOLDLOCK on it.


I need to know whether the following pattern requires me to use HOLDLOCK in a very highly concurrent environment.

The HOLDLOCK hint applies SERIALIZABLE isolation semantics to the hinted table. This is necessary when you want to insert a row only if no row with the same key currently exists, for example.
The underlying issue is the MERGE testing to see if a particular row does not exist, and that condition continuing to be valid until the insert is completed.
Without serializable semantics, there is no row to lock to provide the necessary guarantee. Key-range locking provides the solution in SQL Server by locking the key range any new row would be added to. This is only available under serializable isolation.
A separate INSERT statement is subject to the same fundamental considerations and so also requires an isolation level hint for correct behaviour under high concurrency.
Note that in your example, the target table is also accessed for reading in accordance with the ON and WHERE NOT MATCHED clauses. This is where the range lock is needed to ensure any row found not to match continues not to exist until the insert happens.

There's not enough detail in the question to say why your INSERT experiences concurrency problems (presumably, unique key violations) but the MERGE does not. The devil is always in the detail. Maybe you were just lucky. Maybe the IDs to be inserted are genuinely always disjoint in your MERGE testing.
Regardless, yes, the 'pattern' requires a SERIALIZABLE hint to be safe for concurrent single row inserts. Multi-row inserts are always at risk of a deadlock if the order of rows is unfortunate. Patterns aside, it is better to understand the reason for the hint than to just apply it out of habit.
If your concurrent sessions performing these inserts are guaranteed not to receive the same ID value, the hint is not required. Ask yourself if that guarantee is really rock-solid now and will continue to be forever more.
By the way, HOLDLOCK is a terrible name for this hint and only maintained for backward compatibility. The more modern synonym is SERIALIZABLE.
Finally, this looks odd:
ON (target.ID = source.ID AND ...)

You should only use the ON clause to determine if source and target rows match. The ID column seems like it ought to be a unique identifier. No AND is needed in that case and might be an error.
Related Q & A: SQL Server 2014 Concurrent input issue (includes links to a survey of methods)

Thanks for providing the explanations. My example with the ID and AND was misleading and confusing, I agree. In the real code, it's a combination of a few columns which together make up a "uniqueness" criteria.
